# Sort object by key in descending order

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

This is simple yet most painful question for me.

Take an example of following snippet of code:

```js
const test = {};
test[2] = 'value2';
test[1] = 'value1';
console.log(test);
```

**The result of above snippet is:**

```
{
  1: "value1",
  2: "value2"
}
```

**I want to pass this object as it is with following result:**

```
{
  2: "value2",
  1: "value1"
}
```

**PS:** I tried **Object.keys(test).sort()** and **Object.keys(test).reverse()** and then chained it with function for re-creating the object but nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: Pretty sure it's impossible, because numeric properties are always listed *in order numerically*, aren't they? But property order isn't something any good code should depend on, I think

Comment: If you want to pass *the object itself*, don't think it's possible, though it would be possible if you want to pass a serialized version of the object. (though, on deserialization, if what accepts it is JS-based, it'll turn back into plain numeric order) Sounds like you should use an array instead, maybe

Comment: Object.keys(test).sort().reverse()

Comment: It will just reverse the keys but I want both key and value in expected format.

Comment: Instead of sending the object of your choice send the object as it is and make it as you need in the method that going to process it. In case of associative array, order is always random. Alternately, convert the  associative array to array of objects and convert them into the way your function needs.

Comment: You should not rely on ordering of object keys and if your keys are just integers why not use array in the first place? Just push your values into array and you can simply reverse it then.

Comment: All server side languages gives this feature. A developer (especially Backend) would definitely think about it in future. I feel adding this question here would surely save someone's time. That's my opinion. I've wasted my 3 hours :)

Answer (score 1):

i check this you can use something like this to extend your key and values into another object

{key:"" , value:""}

```js
const test = {};
test[2] = 'value2';
test[1] = 'value1';
test[4] = 'value4';

var r = Object.keys(test).sort().reverse()
console.log(r);

var sorted ={}

//look like JS Sorted this ASC

  r.forEach(k => {
        sorted[k] = test[k]
    });

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));

// So use Array

var sorted =[]


  r.forEach(k => {
        sorted.push({"key":k ,"value": test[k]})
    });

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with positive integer keys. It may kind of work on most browsers (but probably not all) with non-positive integer keys : `[-2]`, `[.2]`, `['2 ']`, etc.

```js
const obj = { '2 ': "value2", '1 ': "value1" };

console.log(obj);

console.log( JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 2).replace(/ ": "/g, '": "') );
```